# Linking dropdownbutton to data in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am building a shiny web app and would like to select dropdown menu options from the unique names in my dataset. Not sure how to do this.

Here is what I have tried:

```
ui <- shinyUI(
 fluidPage(
   headerPanel(
     column(10,offset = 2,
            h1("Test",style= "font-weight: 500;color: #4d3a7d;padding-left: 200;"
               ),h5("testnig"))
   ),
   sidebarLayout(
     fluidRow(
       column(3, offset=1,div(style = "height: 20px;"),
       sliderTextInput(
         inputId = "selectweight",
         label = "Select the weight class:",
         grid = TRUE,
         force_edges = TRUE,
         choices = unique(boxing$division)
       )),
       column(4, offset=0,div(style = "height:200px;"),
              dropdownButton(
                inputId = 'dropdownA',
                label='control',
                icon = icon("user",lib="glyphicon"),
                status='primary',
                circle=TRUE
                ),
              selectInput(inputId = "fightersA",
                          label = "fighters",
                          choices = unique(boxing$names)))),
     mainPanel = mainPanel(
       setBackgroundImage(
         src="may=.png"),
       "just text"
     )
   )
 )
)
server <- function(input,output){
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Here is a sample of the data in boxing

```
name     division      
a           1          
b           1            
c           2
d           3
a           2
f           4
g           5
h           6
```

To reiterate the idea is that the dropdownbutton options should be populated by unique names in my dataset (excluding nan) and the values in my slider should be populated with the unique division values. However currently I only see the dropdown menu icon but cannot see a list of unique names if I click on the dropdown arrow. The same applies to the slider

Comment: I get this error `"Error in sliderTextInput(inputId = "selectweight", label = "Select the weight class:",  : 
  argument "choices" is missing, with no default"`. In addition, please add all required packages. Then, `may.png`, your data `boxing` is missing.

Comment: @Roman may.png is a picture from my local www directory, all required packages have been added. boxing is just an example of the data I am using (I can post a sample of what is inside boxing if this is useful). The issue I am having is trying to get the dropdown menu list to be populated with the unique values in a given dataset

Comment: Yes please add a sample of the data for others to test

Comment: @EliBerkow done

Comment: You have `choices = unique(boxing$names)` but above you called the column `name`

Comment: make sure you add `library(shinyWidgets)` for `sliderTextInput()` but mine works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean?

```
boxing <- read.table(text ="name     division      
a           1          
b           1            
c           2
d           3
a           2
f           4
g           5
h           6", header= T)


library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
ui <- fluidPage(
  dropdownButton(
    inputId = 'dropdownA',
    label='control',
    icon = icon("user",lib="glyphicon"),
    status='primary',
    circle=TRUE,
   selectInput("dropdown", "columns",choices =  unique(boxing$division)),
   uiOutput("Names")
))
server <- function(input,output){
  output$Names <- renderUI({
    req(input$dropdown)
    selectInput("names", "names", choices = boxing[ boxing$division == input$dropdown, 1])
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```